# is it appropriate to tell others my best friend is Allah?

Tags: quran, hadith

Not sure if its appropriate as I fear Allah and so not want to do so to attribute partner to him or been the arrogant one, awuthubilah.

Insha'Allah, please state Quranic hadith reference a company with your answer jazaklahir.

Comment: @azam I think its your post the duplicate of mine.... your asked about yesterday and mine is 2 months ago FYI, jazak Allah Kahir

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/266429) is how the stackexchange works dear Adam. I couldn't close that pointing to this, as this question 'did not have any up voted or accepted answers'. :) Anyways, I didn't ask that question. FYI

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain to us how you are attributing partners to Allah if you say he is Your Friend?

> Insha'Allah, please state Quranic hadith reference a company with your answer jazaklahir.

Personally I think everything is Halal unless someone can give me a direct contradiction to a clear Ayah or Hadith (not open to interruptions when it comes to Halal/Haram).

I truly do not see an issue with someone saying Allah is my friend. What is wrong with that? If you are saying it in derogatory way then it is something else, but if you are saying it as a love to him there shouldn't be an issue.

Edit: It is all based on the intentions (similar to saying we are the children of God, [many scholars](http://islamqa.info/en/26728) disallowed it based on what the attention leads to or something bad down the road). If you mean that Allah is your friend as in a person who you love and he loves I do not see the harm in it. If you mean something else, could be bad.

Additionally, Prophet Ibrahim was not the friend of Allah, he is called "Khalel". In Arabic there is a pretty major difference between Khalel and Sahib. Sahib means someone that knows you while Khalel/Sadeek is someone very close to you. For example, Abu Bakir was called Alsadeek because he was a Khalel of the Prophet PBUH while many Muslim hypocrites are considered Sahaba (someone who lived during the time of the prophet PBUH).

The question you should be asking yourself, why would you want people to know Allah is your friend? Your relationship between you and Allah should be something that is only that, between you and Allah. There is no need to include anyone else which might take you into darker paths of Hypocrisy without even knowing it.

So in my opinion, even thou it is OK to say so, you shouldn't.

Comment: I know the only mentioned, Friend of Allah is our beloved Prophet Abraham. I feel I am not of high status as of our prophet. Is it be a sort of arrogance to call out that my friend is Allah? That's what I am afraid of. The arrogance.

Comment: Hum..... One phrase you mentioned make me feel a bit chill... "Muslim hypocrites are considered Sahaba " By all mean, please elaborate on that one. I know its not related to this question... if you want to open another question for it, I can do that as well, inshaAllah

Comment: @Adam A sahabi is someone who lived during the time of the prophet (follower of the Prophet PBUH), which included some Sahabi's that were Hypocrites (Monafeqeen). Many scholars will attempt to distinguish between the two to make it look "nice", but the prophet PBUH never did. Feel free to open a question and I can definitely give you all the proof from the Hadith and Sunnah of the Prophet PBUH.